# MySQL Insert rows with the help of count

Tags: mysql, count, sql-insert

Hi I am fairly new to MySQL and I've run into a problem I can't solve.
I have a table "option_benefits_id".

```
id | option_id | benefit_id
===========================
 1 |     1     |     1
 2 |     1     |     2
 3 |     1     |     3
 4 |     2     |     1
 5 |     2     |     3
 6 |     2     |     4
```

After a "user" chooses an "option" I want to populate  the"user_option_benefit" table automatically to look as follows:

```
id |  user_id  | option_benefit_id
===========================
 1 |     1     |     1
 2 |     1     |     2
 3 |     1     |     3
 4 |     2     |     4
 5 |     2     |     5
 6 |     2     |     6
```

I've been thinking to use the count command in but don't quite know how to implement it in an Insert Query so that it populates the table.

I would greatly appreciate your help on this.
Thank you,

Comment: When a "user" chooses an "option", I assume you first do the insert in the table `option_benefits_id`, right? With the `INSERT` command, you should get as a result, the `id` of the row inserted. Use this `id` to add the new row in the table `user_option_benefit`. Let me know if i didn't make myself clear.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment.
Each "option" consists out of different "benefits". These are handled independently of the "user".
When the "user" chooses an "option" he should automatically get assigned all the "benefits" connected to that "option".
So if user 1 selects option 2 he should get benefits 1, 3 and 4 assigned via the "option_benefit_id". Maybe I'm making this too complicated?
The reason for separating "options" and "user" is too change the option - benefit constellation without needing to change it for user. I hope this is a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the *user* chooses an option, you should do *X* inserts, where each one is one of the `benefit_id`. To get the *ids* of the benefits, you shouldn't do a `count`. You should retrieve all `benefit_id` for the *option* selected by the user, and then run the *inserts*.

Comment: What would be the best way to do this?
I know I could loop it, but for a large number of users and benefits, this would be quite memory intensive and slow.

Comment: One way could be to add a row into a table `user_option` and there, with the `option_id` and the  `user_id` get all the benefits linked to that option.